# Magento 2.3: Add Tab to product edit page in backend only for grouped type?

Tags: magento2.3, grouped-products, product-edit

i want to add a product tab only for grouped products in the backend product edit page. I cant figure out how to do this, im only able to show the tab to all products. Is this possible, if yes, how?
Maybe someone has done this and can explain how.

Thanks and Best Regards,
Andreas

Comment: i think this perfect  link. But this link is only show backend.--- https://webkul.com/blog/add-product-tab-specific-product-type-custom-module-magento-2/

Comment: I tried that before, but it dont work with the layout file. The Block is ok, when i use it in the ui_compontent/product_form.xml it is shown to all products. But none of the layout files work, grouped or the product_new for all products. Maybe there has something changed in the last magento versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an xml file for layout updates that only apply to grouped products.

In your theme create the following file:

```
app/design/frontend/<your_vendor_name>/<your_theme_name>/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view_type_grouped.xml
```

Here is a quick example of the contents of that file to add a new tab containing a static block

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <!-- product detail tabs -->
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="BLOCK_NAME" as="BLOCK_NAME" group="detailed_info" >
                <arguments>
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string"><![CDATA[TAB_TITLE]]></argument>
                <argument name="tab" xsi:type="string">TAB_NAME</argument>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">TAB_ID</argument>
                <argument name="sort_order" xsi:type="string">10</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response. But i meant the backend product edit page. The code you posted is for frontend product view.

Comment: Ahh, ok. Sorry I misread it.